# Are colons ok in a REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, api, node.js

I see many REST API examples with URIs like `http://<whatever>/widgets` or `http://<whatever>/widget/123`, for a specific thing. For most things I would just stick with the front slash, but when requesting a specific `id` I'd rather use a colon, like `http://<whatever>/widget:123`.

According to what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters) about best practices, there wasn't much about using the colon, specifically. It sounds like it's acceptable, but is it/what might be some pitfalls to using them instead of the slash?

Express.js seems fine with them (as far as code is concerned):
`app.get('/widgets::id', function(req, res){ <...> });`

**Update:** I just stumbled on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2053640/4224506). It's sounding like colons are perfectly fine for this use.

Comment: Colons are used to separate the port from the URL.  *http://whatever.com/widget:123* is telling the browser to open *widget* at *http://whatever.com*'s port 123.  So no, a colon shouldn't be used there.

Comment: That is not correct, it is only for a port number if it is used directly after the .com (or any other tld)

Comment: That `express.js` examples is not the same context as an URL in a browser.   If you are the author of `express.js`, you can do whatever you want there.  The same is not true of the browser URL.

Comment: That it works as part of a 'not covered by specifications' for one library doesn't mean that *other* libraries will be able to properly handled it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering this to close it now that I've finished the REST API and done some testing. Either colon or front slash did fine, however, it became apparent that every live example I could find used front-slash. I think MichaelT brings up the best point. Another library may not work with it. I'm going to extend that and say it's darn likely. Testing software may not be expecting it either since it's not usually done. I also remember somewhere in there thinking that I'd need extra code to handle the colon, but if I left it as a front-slash I could keep my source simpler.

All that being said, I'm going to say that it appears *technically* fine to use the colon in the way I described, but I'm also going to say it may be more trouble than it's worth down the road simply because it seems to go against a well accepted grain. In the end I went with the front-slash... for now. ;)

Answer (score 2):

While it would in most cases work because you use the colon behind the first slashes, I would not advice to use it.
As you can see [here](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html) the colon is a reserved token, it is being used to specify the port number just after the domain name (before any slashes). So using it might give you weird errors.

It is better to stick with either `/` or by using `?foo=1&bar=2`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It does appear to be reserved according to the BNF further down the page though.

Comment: oooh, bad I did not see it, I should read more carefully. I will update the answer.

Comment: I about missed it myself. All good.

Answer (score 1):

Following the specification for URL laid out in the original [RFC1738](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt) or in [RFC3986](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc3986) for URI spec, colon (:) is reserved for specific purposes. The slashes in the path portion of the URL are there to connote a hierarchy.

So while your application does not break when a route with colons in the path matches it does not follow the proposed specification.  The spec is an agreed upon standard.  Your applications can do whatever you want though.